# How to convert a Local Host URL to Heroku with functioning MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, url, heroku

As mentioned I want to convert a Local Host URL to Heroku with functioning MongoDB.
.
Like I have a Heroku App It works on 1 system only since LocalHost is of that system only.
.
So, I want to convert a Local host url to Heroku App URL
.
**Note: My App uses MongoDB and it may cause some errors**
.
Here is the Heroku Link: https://aqueous-scrubland-89229.herokuapp.com/
.
Here's The code of server.js
.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(cors());
var fs = require('fs');
var Message = mongoose.model('Message',{
  name : String,
  message : String
})



var dbUrl = "mongodb+srv://Chat:1234myidisfake@cluster0.ugho3.mongodb.net/Chat?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
      
mongoose.connect(dbUrl, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to DB!');
}).catch(err => {
    console.log('ERROR:', err.message);
});

app.get('/messages', (req, res) => {
  Message.find({},(err, messages)=> {
    res.send(messages);
  })
})

app.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => res.status(204));

app.get('/messages/:user', (req, res) => {
  var user = req.params.user
  Message.find({name: user},(err, messages)=> {
    res.send(messages);
  })
})


app.post('/messages', async (req, res) => {
  try{
    var message = new Message(req.body);

    var savedMessage = await message.save()
      console.log('saved');

    var censored = await Message.findOne({message:'badword'});
      if(censored)
        await Message.remove({_id: censored.id})
      else
        io.emit('message', req.body);
      res.sendStatus(200);
  }
  catch (error){
    res.sendStatus(500);
    return console.log('error',error);
  }
  finally{
    console.log('Message Posted')
  }

})



io.on('connection', () =>{
  console.log('a user is connected')
})


var server = http.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () { 
  console.log("SERVER STARTED PORT: 3000"); 
});
```

Here's the code of index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My First Node App</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 class="display-4">Send Message</h1>
        <br>
        <input id = "name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
        <br>
        <textarea id = "message" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Message Here"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button id="send" class="btn btn-success">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div id="messages">

    </div>
</div>
<script>
   var socket = io();
    $(() => {
        $("#send").click(()=>{
            sendMessage({name: $("#name").val(), message: $("#message").val()});
            var audio1 = new Audio("./whatsapp_incoming.mp3");
            audio1.play();

        })

        getMessages()
    })

    socket.on('message', addMessages)

    function addMessages(message){
        $("#messages").append(`<h4> ${message.name} </h4> <p> ${message.message} </p>`)
        var audio2 = new Audio("./whatsapp_.mp3");
         audio2.play();
    }

    function getMessages(){
      $.get('http://localhost:3000/messages', (data) => {
        data.forEach(addMessages);
      })
    }

    function sendMessage(message){
      $.post('http://localhost:3000/messages', message)
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Again I want to shift all localhosts to Heroku URL's**
.
Screenshots of all the errors:
[Console Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRdYM.png)

[**Message Database Loading Error to work upon**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5BmD.png)

Comment: pls answer.....

Comment: What shows up in your heroku web dyno's console.log? Here's [how to find that log](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-retrieval-via-the-web-dashboard). Please [edit] your question.

Comment: And, please avoid giving us screenshots of error messages. Instead, paste them into your question and indent four spaces.